# How To Move Participant To Top Of FilmStrip Which Is Speaking on Jitsi MEET

Tags: javascript, webrtc, jitsi, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

Jitsi currently shows the user in a random location on the screen when someone starts talking.

I want to move participant to top of participants which is opened his microphone

Because sometimes i cant know the speaker when there are many participants in the meeting. Is there a any way to do it.

[image: Jitsi]